# Is KMIP supported in AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kmip

Is KMIP protocol supported in AWS kms? Have gone through the AWS documents but not found anything about KMIP support in AWS.

Comment: yes it is nopt mentioned anywhere in kmd faw or document, though i have posted a answer to your problem, if it helped you, do accept it as answer so that it may help others in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

No AWS KMS [does not support KMIP protoco](https://info.townsendsecurity.com/encryption-key-management-aws-pillar)l, however awscloudHSM supports third party integrations with `P6R's KMIP adapter allows you to utilize your AWS CloudHSM instances through a standard KMIP interface.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/other-integrations.html